# Fast scoll disabled after changing list view adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a ListView with fastscroll enabled:

```
mList.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

This works very well. But when I change the adapter, I cannot fast scroll anymore.

```
mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

My adapter has getCount() properly implemented. Calling

> mList.setFastScrollEnabled(true);

after setting the new adapter doesn't work either nor adding `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"` to the `ListView` XML works.

Is there any way to reenable fast scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging in the depths of the Android sourcecode, I finally found a solution:

```
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter....
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // We have to post notifyDataSetChanged() here, so fast scroll is set correctly.
    // Without it, the fast scroll cannot get any child views as the adapter is not yet fully
    // attached to the view and getChildCount() returns 0. Therefore, fast scroll won't
    // be enabled.
    // notifyDataSetChanged() forces the listview to recheck the fast scroll preconditions.
    mList.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

`FastScroller.java` has the following method:

```
public void onItemCountChanged(int totalItemCount) {
    final int visibleItemCount = mList.getChildCount();

    ....

    updateLongList(visibleItemCount, totalItemCount);
}
```

When `setAdapter()` is called, FastScroller re-checks the conditions for enabling fast scrolling. But since the new adapter is not fully shown yet, `mList.getChildCount()` returns zero and `updateLongList()` won't enable fast scrolling.

With my fix, the `ListView` gets notified that the underlaying data was changed after the new adapter was fully attached to the view and the preconditions for fast scrolling are now satisfied.